# Angular 4 Stepper Not Working

Tags: angular

I have created a horizontal stepper with some forms in each step.Step 1 includes a user form with some input fields.Unless all the fields are filled stepper wont proceed.But the problem is even if all the fields are filled stepper still wont proceed.What could be the issue?

Stepper.component.html-

```
<mat-horizontal-stepper  [linear]="true">
  <mat-step  [stepControl]="firstStepper">
    <ng-template matStepLabel>Personal Information</ng-template>
  <app-user-form></app-user-form>
</mat-step>

  <mat-step [stepControl]="secondStepper">
    <ng-template matStepLabel>Education</ng-template>
    <app-page2></app-page2>
  </mat-step>

  <mat-step [stepControl]="thirdStepper">
    <ng-template matStepLabel>Additional Information</ng-template>
  </mat-step>
</mat-horizontal-stepper>
```

Stepper.component.ts-

```
import { Component, OnInit,ViewEncapsulation } from '@angular/core';
import {FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators} from "@angular/forms";


@Component({
  selector: 'app-stepper',
  templateUrl: './stepper.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./stepper.component.css'],
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None

})
export class StepperComponent implements OnInit {

  isLinear = true;
  firstStepper : FormGroup;
  secondStepper : FormGroup;
  thirdStepper : FormGroup;
  constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.firstStepper = this.formBuilder.group({
      firstName :['',Validators.required],
      lastName :['',Validators.required],
      address :['',Validators.required],
      city :['',Validators.required],
      pincode :['',Validators.required],
      state :['',Validators.required]

    });
  }

}
```

user-form.component.html-

```
<form class="example-form" [formGroup]="firstStepper">

  <table class="example-full-width" cellspacing="0"><tr>
    <td><mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
      <input matInput placeholder="First name" formControlName="firstName">
      <mat-error *ngIf="firstStepper.controls['firstName'].errors ?.required">Please Enter the First Name</mat-error>
    </mat-form-field></td>
    <td><mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
      <input matInput placeholder="Last Name" formControlName="lastName">
      <mat-error *ngIf="firstStepper.controls['lastName'].errors ?.required">Please Enter the Last Name</mat-error>
    </mat-form-field></td>
  </tr></table>

  <table class="example-full-width" cellspacing="0"><tr><td>
  <mat-radio-group class="example-radio-group" [(ngModel)]="selectedGender" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}">
    <mat-radio-button class="example-radio-button" *ngFor="let gender of genders" [value]="gender">
      {{gender}}
    </mat-radio-button>
  </mat-radio-group>
  </td></tr></table>

  <table class="example-full-width" cellspacing="0">
    <tr>
    <td>
    <mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
      <textarea matInput placeholder="Address" formControlName="address"></textarea>
      <mat-error *ngIf="firstStepper.controls['address'].errors ?.required">Please Enter the Address</mat-error>
    </mat-form-field>
    </td>
      <td><mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
        <input matInput placeholder="Email" [formControl]="emailFormControl">
        <mat-error  *ngIf="emailFormControl.hasError('required')">Please Enter a valid email id</mat-error>
      </mat-form-field>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>

  <table class="example-full-width" cellspacing="0"><tr>
    <td><mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
      <input matInput placeholder="City" formControlName="city">
      <mat-error *ngIf="firstStepper.controls['city'].errors ?.required">Please Enter the City</mat-error>
    </mat-form-field></td>
    <td><mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
      <input matInput placeholder="State" formControlName="state">
      <mat-error *ngIf="firstStepper.controls['state'].errors ?.required">Please Enter the State</mat-error>
    </mat-form-field></td>
    <td><mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
      <input matInput #postalCode maxlength="5" placeholder="Postal Code" formControlName="pincode">
      <mat-error *ngIf="firstStepper.controls['pincode'].errors ?.required">Please Enter the Pincode</mat-error>
      <mat-hint align="end">{{postalCode.value.length}}/5</mat-hint>
    </mat-form-field></td>
  </tr></table>

  <p>
    <button mat-button matStepperNext (click)="saveSanckBar()">Save</button>
  </p>
</form>
```

User-form.component.ts-

```
import {Component, OnInit, ViewEncapsulation} from '@angular/core';
import {FormBuilder, FormControl, FormGroup, Validators} from '@angular/forms';
import {MatSnackBar} from '@angular/material';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-user-form',
  templateUrl: './user-form.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./user-form.component.css'],
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
})
export class UserFormComponent implements OnInit {

  selectedGender: string;
  firstStepper : FormGroup;
  genders=[
    'Male',
    'Female',
    'Others'
  ]

  emailFormControl = new FormControl('', [
    Validators.required,Validators.email
  ]);


  constructor(public snackBar: MatSnackBar, private formBuilder: FormBuilder) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.firstStepper = this.formBuilder.group({
      firstName :['',Validators.required],
      lastName :['',Validators.required],
     address :['',Validators.required],
      city :['',Validators.required],
      pincode :['',Validators.required],
      state :['',Validators.required]

    });

  }
  getErrorMessage() {
    return this.emailFormControl.hasError('required') ? 'You must enter a value' :
      this.emailFormControl.hasError('email') ? 'Not a valid email' :
        '';
  }

  openSnackBar() {
    let snackBarRef = this.snackBar.open(this.selectedGender,'', {
      duration: 1000
    });
  }

  saveSanckBar(){
    if (this.firstStepper.valid) {
      let snackBarRef = this.snackBar.open("Saved Successfully", '', {
        duration: 1000
      });
    }
  }
}
```